# CSVParser.getRecords() yields zero results

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons

I have been using apache.commons.CSVParser for a while without any issues. I know this sounds silly like the dog ate my homework but, the parser doesn’t yield any records suddenly for the past two days now. Records size shows up with a non zero value in the debugger but the list returned from *CSVParser.getRecords()* is zero. Elsewhere I had read the correct way to access the list is to call the *size()* method on the getRecords(), which I have done.
To reemphasize, the code was working fine.
I was using *commons:commons-csv:jar:1.5* for a while, it stopped working and I tried upgrading to 1.9.0 and the behavior is still the same

```
CSVParser records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(DELIMITER).withHeader(blah).
                  withFirstRecordAsHeader().
                  parse(fileReader);
log.info(“Size:”+records.getRecords()); //shows up as 125, say 
List<CSVRecord> recordList = records.getRecords();//0 size!
```

I have written some test code to validate my sanity, and this code works fine

```
FileReader fReader = new FileReader("/tmp/tempexport.csv");
CSVParser records = 
           CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(DELIMITER).
             withHeader("").withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(fReader);
File file = new File("/tmp/tempexport.csv");
System.out.println(Files.lines(file.toPath()).count());
for (CSVRecord record: records.getRecords()) {
            System.out.println(record.get(0)  + 
 "::"+record.get(1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Naming is a bit misleading

(Both: your variables and their method-name)

A parser (even of class `CSVParser`) is a `parser`.

The `records` are a collection of records, that can be obtained using `parser.getRecords()` - as a `List` or `Iterable`.

Actually, the method is more than an [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) *getter*. So `getRecords()` should be renamed to `nextRecords()` to be semantically exact ️.

Note the docs emphasize the *streaming* character of [`getRecords()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html#getRecords--):

> The returned content starts at the **current parse-position** in the stream.

In conclusion, `getRecords()` advances the parse-position with each reading invocation. Once you read the records for logging as `“Size:”+records.getRecords()`, the position in CSV stream advances and may be at end-of-file (EOF) already.

When you want the size or count of records, use the header-names as approximation: [`parser.getHeaderNames().size()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html#getHeaderNames--).

#### See also

- Java Developer Central: [Read CSV files using Apache Commons CSV](https://javadevcentral.com/read-csv-files-using-apache-commons-csv), tutorial

Comment: My apologies, I should have added this in the code. I do invoke ```int recordsSize = records.getRecords().size();``` to initialize the recordSize that I have logged, and it shows up with the correct size

Comment: Sorry, I see your point, thank you

Comment: Perfect, this blew my mind and I was missing the point I had added this logging recently to get the records size. Thank you @hc_dev